# Scatter plot with marginal histograms and convex hulls

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, scatter-plot, convex-hull

I'd like to plot grouped data in a scatter plot with marginal histograms using Matlab. There is a function to do just that: [`scatterhist`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/stats/scatterhist.html).

However, I'm dealing with some visualization issues: I have a large number of data points and many points are printed one over another (changing marker type and marker size doesn't help).

Therefore, I'd prefer to substitute individual points from each group with their convex hull; i.e., if I have 5 groups, the plot would show 5 convex hulls and keep marginal histograms generated from the original data points. Do you know if there is an easy way to do this or if this has already been implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I came up with the following:

1. Use `scatterhist` to create the scatter plot with marginal histograms.
2. `hold on`
3. Use [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) to get the convex hull for each group of points.
4. Use [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) to draw the convex hull.